# passing a pointer to a structure as an argument to a thread cancellation cleanup handler

Tags: c, posix, pthreads

I'm having trouble passing a pointer to a structure as an argument to a thread cancellation cleanup handler. Here's some sample code that blows up when it hits the compiler. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct struct_def {
     /* data */
} struct_def;

struct_def *ptr_to_struct_def;

void *
thread_function(void *arg)
{
     pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, (void *)ptr_to_struct_def); /* correct? */

     /* function continues */
}

int
main()
{
     int err;
     pthread_t tid;

     err = pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, thread_function, (void *)1);

     /* main continues */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are missing the call to

```
pthread_cleanup_pop(0)
```

after the 'function continues' comment. That will make the compiler fail. Check out sample code using push/pop at [opengroup.org](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pthread_cleanup_pop.html).

You also have a few other problems there, as pointed out in other answers.

Here is something that at least **compiles** after fixing all the compiler errors:

```
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct struct_def {
         /* data */
} struct_def;

struct_def *ptr_to_struct_def;

void cleanup (void *arg)
{
      /* Do your cleanup for the thread here */
}

void *
thread_function(void *arg)
{
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, (void *)ptr_to_struct_def); /* correct? */
    /* Function continues */
    pthread_cleanup_pop (0);
}

int
main()
{
    int err;
    pthread_t tid;

    err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_function, (void *)1);
    /* main continues */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the assignment `ptr_to_struct_def = &struct_def;` in the code you posted.
Wait ... did you say compiler? If this doesn't compile - post the compiler error. Though I don't think you meant that.
OK, you did mean that :) Thanks to @Gonzalo I looked into the `/usr/include/pthread.h` and sure enough the push/pop are macros (at least on Linux here):

```
#  define pthread_cleanup_push(routine, arg) \
  do {                                        \
    __pthread_cleanup_class __clframe (routine, arg)
...
#  define pthread_cleanup_pop(execute) \
    __clframe.__setdoit (execute);                        \
  } while (0)
```

What an unpleasant surprise ...

Comment: They are *required* to be macros like this.

Comment: From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cleanup_pop.html: "These functions may be implemented as macros." - doesn't seem like *required* to me. Whether they *can* be implemented in any other way is a different question.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct
{

} struct_def;

struct_def *ptr_to_struct_def;

void * thread_function(void *arg)

int main()
{
     int err,iResult;
     pthread_attr_t sThreadAttr;
     iResult = pthread_attr_init(&sThreadAttr);
     assert(iResult==0);

     pthread_t tid;

     err = pthread_create(&tid1, &sThreadAttr, thread_function, (void *)&ptr_to_struct_def);

 iResult = pthread_join(sThread, NULL);
  assert(iResult==0);

     /* main continues */
#else

thread_function();
#endif

  // the end
  return 0;
}

void * thread_function(void *arg)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With that code, the `ptr_to_struct_def` is undefined/uninitialized that cannot work. It should point to some instance of `struct_def`.

Also I think it is quite uncommon to pass `(void*)1` for unused arguments, just use `0` if you don't use the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, (void *)ptr_to_struct_def);
//-------------------^^^^^^^  where is this function defined/declared?
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the pointer (notice I removed the typedef):

```
typedef struct struct_def {
 /* data */
} struct_def;

struct_def *ptr_to_struct_def;

void *
thread_function(void *arg)
{
     pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, (void *)ptr_to_struct_def); /* correct? */

     /* function continues */
}

int
main()
{
     int err;
     pthread_t tid;

     err = pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, thread_function, (void *)1);

     /* main continues */
}
```